# ASP.NET Session State Server on IIS 7.5 and Windows 2008 - Not Working

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, state

We are moving an application from a hosting environment using IIS 6.0 and ASP.NET session state server (both on Windows 2003) to IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET session state server (on 2008 R2).

We are having a problem, in the new environment, where if a user gets moved across servers in the farm, their session state is lost.  We had this exact problem in the old environment, and fixed the problem using the information in the following article

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325056

However, we are not able to check the part about the application path in IIS 7.5.

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this problem in IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Management Studio, click the Sites tab, and make sure the ID matches the ID on the other web servers.  If you need to change it, click the site in the list,, then click Advanced Settings.  You can change the ID of the web site in that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link it will help with general configuration:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1202777.aspx?Sharing+ASP+NET+State+Service+sessions+between+IIS7+5+and+8+0+doesn+t+work

Although this link is about IIS 7.5 vs IIS 8, what you need to know is .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 are not compatible, and that's key.

I had 2 IIS 7.5 servers in a web farm that suddenly stopped sharing session state correctly even though everything appeared to be configured correctly. Come to find out, one of the boxes had been updated to .NET 4.5 with windows update. Updating the second box to .NET 4.5 fixed things. Here is a link on how to tell what version of .NET you servers are running.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx